# Global storage in React/Nextjs application

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have an application that fetches data, but due to limits on the server, I cannot make infinite requests (429 error).

Therefore I want to fetch data every night and store it in a global storage for all users to use so that the application seems faster and we do not get "too many requests".

I was thinking about Redis, but was thinking NextJs might have something similar. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

it's depand on number of data, the best practice is to use redis the fastest way